# Issue with clearing out a timer in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements that are dynamically created using PHP. I want the user to hover over an icon and the corresponding element to be shown. When the mouse leaves the icon, I want a timer to start and then hide the element. If the mouse enters the shown element, I want to clear the timer. When the mouse leaves that element, I want the timer to start again.

I am having difficulty figuring this out and I cannot figure out why the timer will not clear out. All of the jQuery below is within `document.ready`.

jQuery

```
var $infoIcon = $('.fa-info-circle');
var $trackListing = $('track-listing');
var timer;

// Show listing on hover
$infoIcon.on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).next('.track-listing').fadeIn();
    clearTimeout(timer);

// Start timer when exiting the info icon
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.track-listing').fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
});

// Kill timer when entering listing box
$trackListing.on('mouseenter', function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);

// Start timer when leaving listing box    
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.track-listing').fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
});
```

If you need the PHP, let me know. Also, I have tried putting the `var timer;` outside of the `document.ready` as a global variable and I get the same results.

Comment: This selector is incorrect - you're missing a leading `.` or `#`: `var $trackListing = $('track-listing');`

Comment: You mention that you're adding elements dynamically. When running this code, are both `$infoIcon` and `$trackListing` present in the DOM?

Comment: You need  make sure your events are bound after the elements are added to the document if they are being created dynamically, not just on document ready

Comment: I changed `var timer;` to `var timer = 0;` and also fixed the bug with the incorrect selector and it works like it should now. I am not sure where that answer went... It seems to have disappeared. I will also bind the event after page load. Thank you all for your willingness to help!

Comment: Not because it is my answer, but I'm pretty sure that you was not binding the selector as well. Initializing a variable, in this case, does not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are inserting elements after the page load, try to bind them like this:

```
$(document).on(event, '.selector', function(){});
```

This `delegates` the `event`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using two different timers. One for `$trackListing` and another for `$infoIcon`